# DotNetNuke DDRMenu How to pass current TabID into xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I am writing a DDRMenu template using xsl and I wonder how I can pass the current tabID into the xsl template. Can anyone provide an example on how to pass dynamic attributes into the xsl template files.

Answer (score 1):

A good resource for DDRMenu template examples is this. https://github.com/MarkXA/ddrmenutemplates

The full set of xslt node attributes are documented [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-xslt-templates).

I believe the tabId is the @id attribute:

```
<a href="{@url}" data-tabid="{@id}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but {@id} references the id of any tab in the underlying xml sitemap document. What I want is a reference to the id of the current selected tab. So I need a way to pass this id as a parameter into the xsl document as it is not part of the underlying xml document. This could also be interesting for some other variables that deal with the current tab.